# How to return substring of linq results

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a list of strings:

```
originalList = { "XX.one", "XX.two", "YY.three" }
```

I want to use linq to select and return a list with `{"one", "two"}`.

if I do for example

```
resultList = originalList.FindAll(o => o.StartsWith("XX")));
```

I will get resultList = `{ "XX.one", "XX.two" }` but what I want is resultList = `{ "one", "two" }`

Any way to solve this?

EDIT: Thanks for all who answered, I've chosen the split function of @er-mfahhgk since it does the minimum of manipulation and doesn't depend on size of the prefix.

Comment: Could the original list contain `XX.`? `XX`? `XX.XX`?

Comment: The list always has the dot ".". So it could contain XX.XX but not XX simply

Comment: Hi @mjwills no. It's a controlled input. It will be always XX.<something> or YY.<something> etc... The "something" will always exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SelectWith` your desired string and then using `Split` function on Dot (`.`) you can select the second part like

```
var resultList = originalList.Where(o => o.StartsWith("XX"))
                             .Select(x => x.Split('.')[1])
                             .ToList();
```

And finally your output will be,

```
foreach (var item in resultList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: One reason I think some of the other answers are preferable is that this answer _relies_ on the fact that there is only a single `.` in the string. Some of the other answers don't have that limitation.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = originalList.Where(o => o.StartsWith("XX"))
                         .Select(x=>x.Replace("XX.,""))
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
resultList = originalList.Where(o => o.StartsWith("XX"))
                         .Select(x=>x.Substring(3))
                         .ToList();
```

( edited to correct wording of Substring )

Comment: I don't know why someone would downvote the answer (which works). You only have a typo there (Substrting instead of Substring)